# Pandas get max delta in a timeseries for a specified period

Tags: pandas, numpy, time-series

Given a dataframe with a non-regular time series as an index, I'd like to find the max delta between the values for a period of 10 secs.  Here is some code that does the same thing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
xs = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(200))
# This function is to create a general situation where the max is not aways at the end or beginning
ys = xs**1.2 + 10 * np.sin(xs)

plt.plot(xs, ys, '+-')

threshold = 10
xs_thresh_ind = np.zeros_like(xs, dtype=int)
deltas = np.zeros_like(ys)

for i, x in enumerate(xs):
  # Find indices that lie within the time threshold
  period_end_ind = np.argmax(xs > x + threshold)

  # Only operate when the window is wide enough (this can be treated differently)
  if period_end_ind > 0:
    xs_thresh_ind[i] = period_end_ind

    # Find extrema in the period
    period_min = np.min(ys[i:period_end_ind + 1])
    period_max = np.max(ys[i:period_end_ind + 1])
    deltas[i] = period_max - period_min

max_ind_low = np.argmax(deltas)
max_ind_high = xs_thresh_ind[max_ind_low]
max_delta = deltas[max_ind_low]

print(
    'Max delta {:.2f} is in period x[{}]={:.2f},{:.2f} and x[{}]={:.2f},{:.2f}'
    .format(max_delta, max_ind_low, xs[max_ind_low], ys[max_ind_low],
            max_ind_high, xs[max_ind_high], ys[max_ind_high]))

df = pd.DataFrame(ys, index=xs)

OUTPUT:
Max delta 48.76 is in period x[167]=86.10,200.32 and x[189]=96.14,249.09
```

Is there an efficient pandaic way to achieve something similar?

Comment: The output you have posted compares values at t=86.1 and t=96.14 but these values are more than 10s apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Series from `ys` values, indexed by `xs` - but convert `xs` to be actual timedelta elements, rather than the float equivalent.

```
ts = pd.Series(ys, index=pd.to_timedelta(xs, unit="s"))
```

We want to apply a leading, 10 second window in which we calculate the difference between max and min.  Because we want it to be leading, we'll sort the Series in descending order and apply a trailing window.

```
deltas = ts.sort_index(ascending=False).rolling("10s").agg(lambda s: s.max() - s.min())
```

Find the maximum delta with `deltas[deltas == deltas.max()]`, which gives

```
0 days 00:01:26.104797298    48.354851
```

meaning a delta of 48.35 was found in the interval `[86.1, 96.1)`

Comment: This is great.  I was not aware of the available rolling window functions.  Thanks for this.  Just to go that extra step, would it be possible to interpolate the values at the upper bounds to ensure that we always look at exactly 10s and not miss out on cases where the maximum would have been between at exactly 10s.  In the example about we are looking at 86.1 and 96.1 but there is no datapoint at 96.1, so we are actually looking at a window from 86.1 to 95.83.

Comment: The rolling function takes a `closed` parameter.  If you set it to "both" then your window should be a left-closed right-closed interval and therefore can compare points exactly 10s apart.  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html